# ERROR: too few arguments for format() CONTEXT

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am getting an error -
**ERROR:  too few arguments for format()
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function master_packs.newproccheckupdateadd(text,text) line 6 at EXECUTE
SQL state: 22023**

```
EXECUTE FORMAT ('INSERT INTO "master_packs"."list"("serialNumber","packType","barcode","ownopsNumber","createdAt","updatedAt","assetName","assetTag") 
                    VALUES("IMEI", 0, 0, 0, %s, %s, "assetName", %s) RETURNING "IMEI", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "assetTag", "assetName"');
```

Please advise.
For Reference I have given the whole code below -

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE "master_packs".newProcCheckUpdateAdd("IMEI" text, "battery_pack_number" text) 
language 'plpgsql' AS
$BODY$
declare
retval text;
begin 
    
    EXECUTE FORMAT ('INSERT INTO "master_packs"."list"("serialNumber","packType","barcode","ownopsNumber","createdAt","updatedAt","assetName","assetTag") 
                    VALUES("IMEI", 0, 0, 0, %s, %s, "assetName", %s) RETURNING "IMEI", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "assetTag", "assetName"');
                    
    update "master_packs".list SET "assetName" = "IMEI"::bigint where battery_pack_number = "assetName";  -- deallocate
    update "master_packs".list SET "assetName" = "battery_pack_number" where "serialNumber" = "IMEI"::bigint; -- allocate
    
end;
$BODY$;

    -- "master_packs".list("IMEI") is true and length("IMEI") = 15;
    -- INSERT INTO "master_packs".list("serialNumber","assetName") VALUES(("IMEI" :: bigint) , "battery_pack_number")
    
CALL "master_packs".newprocCheckUpdateAdd('112233', 'b12345566');
SELECT * FROM "master_packs".list ORDER BY "serialNumber" ASC;
```

while Calling the procedure I am getting the error.
Please Advise.

Comment: Are you using Postgresql or Oracle (plsql)?

Comment: I am using Postgresql.

Comment: Simply provide an argument containing the value for each placeholder in the format string.

Comment: Side note: `"IMEI"` and `"assetName"` don't make sense in the `VALUES` clause as there is no row that columns can be taken from.

Comment: so the data has to be transferred from .csv file which had 2 columns (imei, assetName), but the masterpack on our server has couple of columns "serialNumber","packType","barcode","ownopsNumber","createdAt","updatedAt","assetName","assetTag"  

where serialNumber = imei and assetname = batterypack number

Comment: so after we upload the.csv file - it should update or create columns according to the entries in .csv
For example - if the imei of .csv file = 123
which is already there in masterpack - it has to update the assetname  in the respective column. but the columns having different names in masterpack should just copy what is there in existing masterpack entries.

Comment: Please GUIDE. I am unable to trace the issue.

Comment: You need to spend some time here [Dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). Then you would know that the placeholders are `$N` where N is a number  and not `%s` and that you have to provide values for the placeholders.

Comment: I should had added `%s` is a placeholder for a string in [format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) and what you are looking in that context is `%L`(literal). In any case including the one I mentioned previously you need to provide values to match the placeholders. Otherwise you get the error you reported.

Comment: Thank you so much, Adrian Klaver. I will certainly work on that.